# Can I use non-bootstrap icons in bootstrap-vue components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, bootstrap-vue

I know bootstrap has a ton of icons, but they are missing stuff that I need,
so I was thinking about using an external icon base eg. fontawesome.

So with bootstrap I can apply its icons to components eg. like this:

```
<b-avatar class="mr-3" icon="chat-right-text"></b-avatar>
```

I was hoping that I could do the same with other icons expecting something like this to work:

```
<b-avatar class="mr-3" icon="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></b-avatar>
```

But I ended up with an empty icon.

Everything is installed correctly, since this works fine:

```
<font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-circle-info" />
```

Is there a way to use external icons in bootstrap components?

Comment: Did you check the section on [custom content](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/avatar#custom-content)?

Comment: I missed it. After trying that now I feel it kinda works, but not really. it feels like the icon was just added inside the rather than being the component (is too small and feels out of place).